# expected unqualified-id before ‘or’ token

Tags: c++

I am getting the 'expected unqualified-id before ‘or’ token' error in C++ 14 language. My code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
  int s, t, a, b, m, n, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, i;
  int ap[100], or[100], ap1[100], or1[100];
  cin >> s >> t;
  cin >> a >> b;
  cin >> m >> n;
  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
     cin >> ap[i];
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     cin >> or[i];
  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
     ap1[i] = ap[i] + a;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     or1[i] = or[i] + b;
  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
     if ((ap1[i] >= 7) && (ap1[i] <= 10)) 
       count1++;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     if ((or1[i] >= 7) && (or1[i] <= 10))  
       count2++;
  cout << count1 << endl;       
  cout << count2 << endl;       
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: [`or` is a keyword in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/or). You can't use it for variables.

Comment: oh my goodness, I learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 'or' is an `alternative operator` in `C++`.
See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

You could observe the same error with a program as simple as:

```
int main() {
    int or;
}
```

In summary, don't try to use keywords like `and`, `or`, `not` etc. as identifiers. (See the complete list in the link.)

Comment: This is why you can write an `operator or(int n){...}` function for a class and it is the same as `operator ||(int n){...}`. All this happens before the preprocessor is run.